# Alternative relationship in the same Laravel relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relation

In my model, i created this relationship...

```
public function traduzione(): HasOne
    {
        $check = $this->hasOne(Linguaofferte::class,'id_offerta')->where('tradattiva','=',1)->where('lingua','=',$this->currentLang )->first();
        if(empty($check)){
            return $this->hasOne(Linguaofferte::class,'id_offerta')->where('lingua','=', config()->get('warp.default_platform_language') );
        }else{
            return $this->hasOne(Linguaofferte::class,'id_offerta')->where('lingua','=',$this->currentLang );
        }
    }
```

In the relation, an initial check if the offer translation in the chosen language exists.
If the translation doesn't exist, then it get the translation in the default language.

If i execute the query with the 'with' method, e.g.
`Offerta::where(...condition..)->with('traduzione')->first()`
the check in the relation is not considered and always takes the last return.

If instead i get the translation after the query, it works, e.g.

```
$offer = Offerta::where(..condition..)->first();
$translation = $offer->traduzione;
```

How is that? Is there a possibility of creating an alternative relationship in the same relation? Suggestions welcome!

Comment: during `with` there is no object context, so `$this->currentLang` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with nested [default models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models:)

the code below is not tested but you can get the idea

```
public function traduzione(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Linguaofferte::class, 'id_offerta')
        ->where('tradattiva', '=', 1)
        ->where('lingua', '=', $this->currentLang)
        ->withDefault(function (Linguaofferte $linguaofferte, Offerta $offferta) {
            return $linguaofferte
                ->where('id_offerta', '=', $offferta->id)
                ->where('lingua', '=', config()->get('warp.default_platform_language'))
                ->first();
        })
        ->withDefault(function (Linguaofferte $linguaofferte, Offerta $offferta) {
            return $linguaofferte
                ->where('id_offerta', '=', $offferta->id)
                ->where('lingua', '=', $this->currentLang)
                ->first();
        });
}
```